# Efficient way of counting a large content from a cloumn or a two in a database using selected time period

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I need to list number of column1 that have been added to the database over the selected time period (since the day the list is requested)-daily, weekly (last 7 days), monthly (last 30 days) and quarterly (last 3 months). for example below is the table I created to perform this task.

```
      Column      |            Type             |                      Modifiers
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
column1            character varying (256)        not null default nextval
date               timestamp without time zone    not null default now()
coloumn2           charater varying(256)          ..........
```

Now, I need the total count of entries in column1 with respect the selected  time period.
Like,

```
     Column 1     |            Date             |           Coloumn2
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
abcdef              2013-05-12 23:03:22.995562    122345rehr566
njhkepr             2013-04-10 21:03:22.337654    45hgjtron
ffb3a36dce315a7     2013-06-14 07:34:59.477735    jkkionmlopp
abcdefgggg          2013-05-12 23:03:22.788888    22345rehr566
```

From above data, for daily selected time period it should be count= 2

I have tried doing this query

```
select count(column1) from table1 where date='2012-05-12 23:03:22';
```

and have got the exact one record matching the time stamp. But I really needed to do it in proper way I believe this is not an efficient way of retrieving the count. Anyone who could help me know the right and efficient way of writing such query would be great. I am new to the database world, and I am trying to be efficient in writing any query.
Thanks!
**[EDIT]**
*Each query currently is taking 175854ms to get process. What could be the efficient way to lessen the time to have it processed accordingly.* Any help would be really great. I am using Postgresql to do the same.

Comment: What significance is column1? Don't you just want "the number of rows"? Or do you want the number of *different* values in column1 for the time period?

Comment: Coloumn1 is unique, I need the number of rows or data depending on the selected time period, for example, if I wanted to have data for last 7 days(weekly) I should get the total count of data that are in column1 within that period of time since today.

Comment: Since the database is so huge,I needed to make the query which is efficient, currently it is taking 175854ms to process the query. Therefore, I am curious, if is there any efficient way of doing this and optimize a bit?

Comment: Again, why are you harping on about column1??? Nothing you have said indicates that the contents of column1 is relevant in any way. Yes or no: Do you want the number of *rows* within the last 7 days?

Comment: There are few others columns in the table that are/may left blank or null depending on some back end logic to fill it accordingly, and so does column 1 might. Therefore, I don't need the total number of rows in the table using any column within certain period of time(because it would vary). I intend to retrieve only the count of column 1 content with selected period of time(weekly.daily,monthly etc.) Hope I answered, and I will add it to the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be efficient, conditions should compare values of the sane type as the columns being compared. In this case, the column being compared - `Date` - has type `timestamp`, so we need to use a range of `tinestamp` values.

In keeping with this, you should use `current_timestamp` for the "now" value, and as confirmed by the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html), subtracting an `interval` from a `timestamp` yields a `timestamp`, so...

For the last 1 day:

```
select count(*) from table1
where "Date" > current_timestamp - interval '1 day'
```

For the last 7 days:

```
select count(*) from table1
where "Date" > current_timestamp - interval '7 days'
```

For the last 30 days:

```
select count(*) from table1
where "Date" > current_timestamp - interval '30 days'
```

For the last 3 months:

```
select count(*) from table1
where "Date" > current_timestamp - interval '3 months'
```

Make sure you have an index on the Date column.

---

If you find that the index is not being used, try converting the condition to a between, eg:

```
where "Date" between current_timestamp - interval '3 months' and current_timestamp
```

Logically the same, but may help the optimizer to choose the index.

---

Note that `column1` is irrelevant to the question; being unique there is no possibility of the *row* count being different from the number of different values of `column1` found by any given criteria.

Also, the choice of "Date" for the column name is poor, because a) it is a reserved word, and b) it is not in fact a date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct column1) from table1 where date > '2012-05-12 23:03:22';
```

I assume "number of column1" means "number of distinct values in `column1`.

**Edit:**
Regarding your second question (speed of the query): I would assume that an index on the date column should speed up the runtime. Depending on the data content, this could even be declared `unique`.

Comment: Thank you Frank, yes it is distinct values. How would I count on daily basis. Do I require to use TO_DATE? to have the efficient result. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Just use the date one day before today as a parameter for "within one day", and one week before today as the parameter for "within the last week".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count number of records between two dates:

```
select count(*)
from Table1
where "Date" >= '2013-05-12' and "Date" < '2013-05-13'
-- count for one day, upper bound not included

select count(*)
from Table1
where "Date" >= '2013-05-12' and "Date" < '2013-06-13'
-- count for one month, upper bound not included

select count(*)
from Table1
where
    "Date" >= current_date and
    "Date" < current_date + interval '1 day'
-- current date
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, it is really helpful, if I needed to count daily basis without mentioning the dates and have myself use the system date, so is there any now() condition that I am suppose to use for querying? for example which can take my system date and query accordingly? Just curious

Comment: how can I make it efficient, currently it is taking 175854ms to process each query. any suggestion would be really great!

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your wording is

```
select date_trunc('day', "date"), count(*)
from t
where "date" >= '2013-01-01'
group by 1
order by 1
```

Replace `'day'` for `'week'`, `'month'`, '`quarter`' as needed.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Create an index on the "date" column.

Answer (score 1):

To throw another option into the mix...

Add a column of type "date" and index that -- named "datecol" for this example:

```
create index on tbl_datecol_idx on tbl (datecol);
analyze tbl;
```

Then your query can use an equality operator:

```
select count(*) from tbl where datecol = current_date - 1; --yesterday
```

Or if you can't add the date datatype column, you could create a functional index on the existing column:

```
create index tbl_date_fbi on tbl ( ("date"::DATE) );
analyze tbl;
select count(*) from tbl where "date"::DATE = current_date - 1;
```

Note1: you do not need to query "column1" directly as every row has that attribute filled due to the `NOT NULL`.

Note2: Creating a column named "date" is poor form, and even worse that it is of type `TIMESTAMP`.